# Create modal view on jquery mobile using html

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, modal-dialog, lightbox, shadowbox

I am creating a mobile website using HTML5 and jquery mobile. I am currently trying to create a modal view to show images in. I have tried using shadowbox and lightbox but in both cases the modal view opens but then the page transitions to a new blank page. Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0/demos/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="CodeGeneral.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0/demos/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="CodeAppDetailScreen.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0/demos/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleMaincss.css">


    <!--Shadowbox-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox/shadowbox.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox/shadowbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Shadowbox.init();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
//Content

    <div id="viewport">
    <a id="ss1" onclick="return false" href="Screenshots/ss1.png" rel="shadowbox[ScreenShot]" ><img src="Screenshots/ss1.png"></a>
    <a id="ss2" onclick="return false" href="Screenshots/ss2.png" rel="shadowbox[ScreenShot]" ><img src="Screenshots/ss2.png"></a>
    <a id="ss3" onclick="return false" href="Screenshots/ss3.png" rel="shadowbox[ScreenShot]" ><img src="Screenshots/ss3.png"></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope if you can give [PhotoSwipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html) a try. It's a 3rd party plugin that can be easily integrated with jQuery Mobile.

I'm not sure if the following plugins works for you or not?!
[jQuery Mobile Pagination Plugin](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_mobile_pagination_plugin/)
[Diapo slideshow](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/diapo/)